# How to toggle style in animation using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add `opacity: 0.5` to `li` when it's clicked and toggle the opacity back to `opacity:1` when clicked again with animation?

```
$('li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('completed');
    });
});
```

Is there any simple solution like toggling between classes or do I need to add logic to check the current opacity and change accordingly? I don't want to change markup or CSS but would like to do it through jQuery.

Comment: Have you considered making another class that sets the opacity and toggling it along with the class `completed`?

Comment: @aug Your suggestion will definitely work, but I would like to do it with jQuery only and not adding anything in CSS, for some reasons. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use math for that :)

```
$('li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: (0.5 / $(this).css("opacity"))
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('completed');
    });
});
```

Comment: I voted your answer up as it works. But could you explain the math part? Thanks

Comment: for you it would be `0.5 / $(this).css("opacity")`

because for the first time, it would calc 0.5 / 1 and give you 0.5.. next time it would do 0.5/0.5 and give you 1

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('li').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':animated')) return; //ignore click while animating
    
    var opacity = $(this).css('opacity') == 1 ? 0.5 : 1;
        
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: opacity
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('completed');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Click Here</li>
    <li>Click Here</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a flag

```
$('li').on('click', function () {

    var opacity,
        flag = $(this).data('flag');

    if ( flag ) {
        opacity = 1;
    } else {
        opacity = 0.5;
    }

    $(this).animate({
        opacity: opacity
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('completed');
        $(this).data('flag', !flag);
    });
});
```

*(Really verbose on purpose)*

```js
$('li').on('click', function () {

    var opacity,
        flag = $(this).data('flag');

    if ( flag ) {
        opacity = 1;
    } else {
        opacity = 0.5;
    }

    $(this).animate({
        opacity: opacity
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('completed');
        $(this).data('flag', !flag);
    });
});
```

```css
li {color : red; cursor: pointer; margin: 20px 0 0 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Click to fade</li>
    <li>Click to fade</li>
    <li>Click to fade</li>
    <li>Click to fade</li>
    <li>Click to fade</li>
    <li>Click to fade</li>
</ul>
```

The less verbose version

```
$('li').on('click', function () {
    var flag = $(this).data('flag');

    $(this).fadeTo(500, flag ? 1 : 0.5, function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('completed').data('flag', !flag);
    });
});
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution - test a bool.  It's hard to get into trouble.  These are all good solutions. Props for adding the "condensed" version.

Comment: @SurrealDreams - The real advantage is that there are no lookups of styles, that can be unreliable, depend on what browsers return etc. and it works with anything, it's a toggle function, and one could stick "whatever" in the two toggled states *(the `if` condition)*